# How to SSH tunnel to a destination host resolved via internal DNS on the bastion host

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a remote host `123.456.789` that I am able to SSH into. From within the SSH host, a **private** database host can be accessed.

I would like to forward my local port on my computer TO the **private** database host **via** the remote host (using it as a bastion - if this is the correct terminology).

---

I'm trying to do:

```
ssh 3306:my-private-host-database.example:3306 example@123.456.789
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 3306:my-private-host-database.example:3306: Name or service not known
```

So the issue seems to be that `my-private-host-database.example` resolves correctly **only** on the internal dns of the bastion `123.456.789` host.

Is this possible to be done?

Comment: `3306:my-private-host-database.example:3306` seems the argument to a `-L` or `-R` options. Without one of them, it is probably just parsed as `hostname` in a simple `ssh hostname` (the whole expression, including the two 3306 and the colons). Are you trying to set up some port forwarding? Or to simply connect to a private host through a bastion?

Comment: Thanks sorry, that was a typo :) - I did have a `-L` in there.

Comment: Still strange. When you connect to `123.456.789`, it doesn't immediately try to also establish a connection to the `-L`'s argument. You shouldn't get any error. In other words, `ssh port:unreachable_host:port working_user@working_host` gives no error (then, trying to connect to the local `port` would time out). Are those really the commands you are running and the error you are seeing?

Comment: Hmmm you're correct.. Let me double check this.

Comment: Yup seems you're correct! I was just missing the `-L` argument. Thank you! Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on a troubleshooting session we had in comments)

In

```
ssh 3306:my-private-host-database.example:3306 example@123.456.789
```

the string `3306:my-private-host-database.example:3306` seems to be the argument to a missing `-L` or `-R` option. Without the option, that whole string is taken as a host name (including the two `3306`s and the colons).

Since you are trying to set up a local port forwarding, that command should likely be

```
ssh -L 3306:my-private-host-database.example:3306 example@123.456.789
```